# Read XML from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Good, again I ask your help, I have an XML document this link: http://inlivefm.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schedule System="Jazler">
    <Event status="happening" startTime="23:20:05" eventType="song">
        <Announcement Display=""/>
        <Song title="BEAUTIFUL NOW (FEAT JON BELLION)">
            <Artist name="ZEED">
            </Artist>
            <Jazler ID="154"/>
            <PlayLister ID=""/>
            <Media runTime="03:34"/>
            <Expire Time="23:23:38"/>
        </Song>
    </Event>
</Schedule>
```

and I tried to reproduce for an html code that was this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
p{
    background-color:#FFFBDB;
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  /*  Busca el archivo NowOnAir.xml */
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "NowOnAir.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      /*Buscar el tag <Event> e ir repitiendo el proceso hasta el final (bucle) */
      $(xml).find('Event').each(function(){
        /*Tomar los valores de startTime*/
        var startTime = $(this).attr('startTime');

        /*Buscar el tag <Song> y repetir bucle*/
        $(this).find('Song').each(function(){
          /*Tomar los valores de title*/
          var title = $(this).attr('title');

          /*Buscar el tag <Artist> y repetir bucle*/
          $(this).find('Artist').each(function(){
            /*Tomar los valores de name*/
            var artist = $(this).attr('name');

            /*Buscar el tag Expire y repetir bucle*/
            $(this).find('Expire').each(function(){
              var time = $(this).attr('Time');
              $('.cancion').append("<p>Inici: "+startTime+"<br>Artista: "+artist+"<br>Tema: "+title+"<br>Finalitza: "+time+"</p>");
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cancion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but I'm not getting, it must be my mistake, if someone I get thanked. Thanks again

Comment: what are you receiving on your success callback?

Comment: with this code can get titlo and the artist who estam inserted into xml

Comment: Is your success function running? Have you checked the value of `xml` with `console.log`? Why don't you have an error function? Have you looked at your developer tools? Does the console show any errors? Does the network tab show the request and response you expect?

Comment: I suppose that the code is with some error which does not visualize what I want, since I've used a similar code and removed information from XML but was to another function and worked well, now this still tried to change some things and researched on the internet but without success, so I came for help

Comment: Don't just say "but I'm not getting it"; explain in detail what the error is, line in the code, error messages, what debugging have you done? Right now your question falls under `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
          /*  Busca el archivo NowOnAir.xml */
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "NowOnAir.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                /*Buscar el tag <Event> e ir repitiendo el proceso hasta el final (bucle) */
                $(xml).find('Event').each(function(){
                    /*Tomar los valores de startTime*/
                    var startTime = $(this).attr('startTime');

                    /*Buscar el tag <Song> y repetir bucle*/
                    $(this).find('Song').each(function(){
                        /*Tomar los valores de title*/
                        var title = $(this).attr('title');
                        var artist;

                        /*Buscar el tag <Artist> y repetir bucle*/
                        $(this).find('Artist').each(function(){
                            /*Tomar los valores de name*/
                            artist = $(this).attr('name');
                        });

                        /*Buscar el tag Expire y repetir bucle*/
                        $(this).find('Expire').each(function(){
                            var time = $(this).attr('Time');
                            $('.cancion').append("<p>Inici: "+startTime+"<br>Artista: "+artist+"<br>Tema: "+title+"<br>Finalitza: "+time+"</p>");
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
          });
        });
```

Tweaked your existing posted code to work as is:

Issues in your code:

1. There was a scope issue, you have nested the loop on 'Expire' node inside the 'Artist' node, were as both these nodes are at the same level (are siblings). Hence, 'Expire' is inaccessible inside 'Artist'.

Solution:
 1. Moved the 'Artist' loop outside of 'Artist' node. Issue fixed.
 2. 'artist' variable declaration moved out of the 'artist' loop and moved    to its parent loop on the 'Song' node.

If you want your code to work the way it, then you need to make the 'Expire' node child of the 'Artist' node. This way, if there are multiple artist's in the node then all will be appended to the div. In my fix above, this case is not addressed.

Comment: Thank you all for the messages, following the accession of the method and the correct code of Sudhanshu Singh got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem :

```
$(this).find('Expire').each(function(){
```

You've placed this inside:

```
$(this).find('Artist').each(function(){
```

However Expire is on the same level as artist and not a child of it. Because of this the content of that function will never run and the .append will not run. Correct your syntax and try again.